# simple jQuery show() Fails

Tags: jquery, show, hidden

I have the following tiny file, which should hide the one line of output with CSS then show that line with `jQuery`. However, the `jQuery` `show()` fails to show the line (no output in browser)...

```js
$(function(){ 
  $('#hi').show(); 
});
```

```css
#hi{visibility:hidden;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <span id="hi">hi</span>
</body>
```

Andrew

Comment: `show` works only on `display` - not on visibility. Change your css to `display: none` and you will see the code working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go with a solution https://jsfiddle.net/bb7ms7zo/

```js
$(function(){ 
  $('#hi').css({
     visibility: 'visible'
  }); 
});
```

```css
#hi{visibility:hidden;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="hi">hi</span>
```

`jQuery show` method is being used for `diplay:block` property, whereas in `CSS` you have used `visibility:hidden;`.

So you need to do `visibility: 'visible'`.

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery's [show()](http://api.jquery.com/show/) function manipulates the element's `display` property and not `visibility`. The possible values are `display:block`, `display:inline`, `display:none` or the `initial` value.

Hence, in order for your code to work either change the CSS property in your css

```
#hi{display:none;}
```

OR

Change your jQuery code to

```
$('#hi').css({
   visibility: 'visible'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In This Case If you want to work with `Show()` then you have to use

```
#hi{display:none;}
```

then it will work.

Or If you want to stay with using visibility then try the below code

```
$("#hi").css('visibility', 'visible');
```